# Executing jest test statements from the node repl

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there any way to execute jest test statements line by line (either using a jest setting or through the node repl)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use node debugging, like: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/ . Then, you can set a breakpoint at the first line of your test and step through from there.

Visual Studio code has a debugger that makes this easy, and you can use extensions like Ora's popular [jest](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/releases/tag/v4.0.0) extension to auto run all your tests and add a link to easily launch debugging on any failing test.